# Why I can't see the "related" questions?

Tags: bug, status-completed, related-questions

For the last two weeks (at least) I am unable to view the "related" questions. I can see the linked questions but not the related. Why this happens?

Comment: I have reported this on [meta.se]: [The list of related questions is shown empty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/350569). A moderator marked it ([meta-tag:status-review]), other than that there was not much feedback so far.